# Entity Framework cleaner way of multiple table includes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a large model that I'm trying to obtain from the database and am using the .Include(string) extension method to load all the entities that I need. It is getting very messy and I now have 18 rows that are also long in horizontal length where I have to chain them together.

Example:

```
var myModel = repository.Queryable()
.Include("Entity1")
.Include("Entity1.Entity2")
.Include("Entity1.Entity2.Entity3")
.Include("Entity1.Entity2.Entity3.Entity4")
.Include("Entity1.Entity2.Entity3.Entity4.Entity5")
```

and so on!

There must be a better way of doing this? I'm struggling to find any help on a better way. I also then have a fair few condition I need to apply on each table for example removed flags on tables need to be checked. I'm wondering whether it would just be easier to get this from the database using another method.

Comment: Why doesn't lazy-loading work for you?

Comment: I'm returning the whole lot in an api so this then becomes a view model

Answer (score 1):

If you write .Include("Entity1.Entity2.Entity3.Entity4.Entity5") all related entities are eager loaded, not just the last. So you can write just

```
repository.Queryable().Include("Entity1.Entity2.Entity3.Entity4.Entity5");
```

and you will have loaded Entity3 as well as Entity5. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232#eagerLevels for more details, especially

> Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always being in all related entities.

Also I think that much better is type safe variant of extension method Include. It is more robust to properties renaming etc. than string variant.

```
repository.Queryable().Include(x => x.Entity1.Entity2.Entity3.Entity4.Entity5);
```

Comment: I'll test that out tomorrow. I guess I'll have to do filtering when I map this to a model

Comment: This stringing together will only work if they're 1:1 relationships wont it. Problem is there are 1:n relationships in there too

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of generic repository with the option to include the navigation properties of an entity :

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        ...
        public virtual T GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null)
        {
            var set = SetWithIncludes(includeProperties);
            return predicate != null ? set.FirstOrDefault(predicate) : set.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        protected IQueryable<T> SetWithIncludes(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> set = DbSet;

            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (var include in includes)
                {
                    set = set.Include(include);
                }
            }

            return set;
        }
    }
```

and the actual usage :

```
_entityRepository.GetOne(c => c.Id == id, new Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[] { c => c.SubEntityOrEntityCollection.SubSubEntityOrEntityCollection });
```